# Cálculo de comprimento e largura

Tags: c, matlab, programação-estruturada

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Octave, que é muito parecido com MathLab e com C, que calcula a altura e e largura de um objeto, que nessa caso é uma semente.

O programa recebe uma imagem de entrada e em seguida binariza. Gostaria de saber como calcular essa distância, pois já pesquisei muito e não consegui entender muito bem.

Uma das questões é: Como encontrar os dois pontos na imagem para medir a distância entre eles? Porque tipo, no meu pensamento eu tenho que chegar no “meio” do objeto, na parte superior e “descer” uma linha até o fim do objeto, dessa forma eu teria uma linha de pixels, que após realizar uma regra de três com outro objeto de tamanho conhecido, eu obteria essa informação.

Grato desde já.

Comment: O que você fez até agora?

Comment: Estou no processo de aquisição das imagens. Porém fiquei com essa dúvida aí quando comecei a pensar no código.

Comment: Que formato é o arquivo de imagem?

Comment: A imagem de entrada é em .jpg. Em seguida eu torno ela preto e branco.

Answer (score 1):

Se for uma imagem colorida,

```
I = imread("minhaImagem.png");
img = I(1);
[width, height, colorDepth] = size(img);

disp(width); disp(height)
```

Se for uma imagem monocromática,

```
I = imread("minhaImagem.bmp");
img = I(1);
[width, height] = size(img);

disp(width); disp(height)
```

Se for uma imagem com animação,

```
I = imread("minhaImagem.gif");
img = I(1);
[width, height, colorDepth, timing] = size(img);

disp(width); disp(height)
```

Comment: Prezado, o que acontece na linha 2,3,4 ?

Comment: Como assim? Não está claro? Ele pega o primeiro item de `I` e extrai as dimensões desse item.

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/imread.html